# What is a possible cause of "Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set" when making a web service call?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am making a SOAP web service call in a Java application to a third party web service. Java classes used to look up the web service, transfer the data and make the SOAP request were generated using Apache CXF libraries from a WSDL.

While most of the requests to the service succeed, I am facing issues with some calls failing with **"Fault string, and possibly fault code, not set"** exception message. Unfortunately I cannot pull the exact stack trace or request/response objects so I am practically in the dark.

I am wondering if it's safe to assume that this problem is happening because of bad response sent from the web service, or if this problem could be happening on the client side also. In addition, what could be the root cause of this exception? Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it response from third-party webservice method, it seems this issue on their side. Another one possible thing that fault string and fault code are request params and you didn't specify them and there is a validation message.